# Thread Abortion in asmx web service

Tags: asp.net, asmx

This error was happened on-and-off when executing the asmx service in background schedule job in production server. In my localhost it work fine. I had try to solve this thread abortion issue by adding System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout to 90 seconds and longer when process the background job but it still persist. The thread abortion sometimes might occur in different stage but mostly occurs in below stack trace.

```
   System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
       at System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.recv(IntPtr socketHandle, Byte* pinnedBuffer, Int32 len, SocketFlags socketFlags)
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, SocketError& errorCode)
       at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
       at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
       at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.XdrStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
       at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.XdrStream.ReadBytes(Int32 count)
       at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.XdrStream.ReadInt32()
       at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.XdrStream.ReadNextOperation()
       at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.XdrStream.ReadOperation()
       at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version11.GdsDatabase.ReadOperation()
       at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.ReadSingleResponse()
       at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.ReadResponse()
       at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.ReadGenericResponse()
       at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version12.GdsStatement.Execute()
       at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand cmd)
       at NHibernate.AdoNet.NonBatchingBatcher.AddToBatch(IExpectation expectation)
       at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session)
       at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.UpdateOrInsert(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session)
       at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Int32[] dirtyFields, Boolean hasDirtyCollection, Object[] oldFields, Object oldVersion, Object obj, Object rowId, ISessionImplementor session)
       at NHibernate.Action.EntityUpdateAction.Execute()
       at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)
       at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list)
       at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions()
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush()
       at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Commit()
```